# Proper way of getting a reference of other pre-exist object by calling method?

Tags: php, object, methods, reference

I'm trying to call an object using method and I got stuck.

Lets suppose that I have a class named `Entity` which used to pseudo-struct-type variable.

The object `Entity` is usually have multiple relation among other `Entity` instances. So, I make a class `EntityModule` to handle database save, load, and possibly other handy methods.

What I'm trying to do is..

Lets if I want to insert `Entity` object to the table.
With a method `Entity->save()`, I want to call `EntityModule->saveEntity()` method from pre-exist `EntityModule` obejct.

How should I get this?
I think, just using other instantiated object inside a class, its very weired.

.. Its very confusing for amateur.. Following is my example.

```
<?php
class Container
{
    public function __get($varName)
    {
        if(!isset($this->varName)) {
            // Can it be more simpler?
            switch($varName) {
                case 'PDO':
                    $this->PDO('dbdbdb');
                    break;
                case 'SessionStorage':
                    $this->SessionStorage($this->PDO);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // This is weird method.. can it be more simpler?
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        $n = count($args);
        if($n === 0) {
            $this->$method = new $method();
        } elseif($n === 1) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0]);
        } elseif($n === 2) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1]);
        } elseif($n === 3) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
        } elseif($n === 4) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
        } elseif($n === 5) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4]);
        } elseif($n === 6) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5]);
        } elseif($n === 7) {
            $this->$method = new $method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5], $args[6]);
        };
    }
}
?>
```

Using the container, I try to instantiate object dynamically.

```
class Schema
{
    public $id;
    public $type;
    public $name;
    public $desc;

    public function __construct(int $id = false, $type = 0, $name = 'Temporal schema name', $desc = 'No description.')
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->desc = $desc;
        return;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        if(!isset($ctn->SchemaModule)) {
            // This is another weird part.
            // Is this the right way to make a class? Call a random instance inside the class? Doesn't it wierd?????????? ???? ?.??  ??? mentalbreak.
            $ctn->SchemaModule->save($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any (short) code examples which showcases what you're trying, and any issues you're having with it?

Comment: Thanks ChristianF. I just edit the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to do, I do think that you might have overcomplicated things a bit. Or at least, made it overly abstract.

The `__call()` magic method, as well as the other "overloading" magic methods (`__get()` & `__set()`), should be used very sparingly. As they make things a lot more complicated, breaks IDE-support and is generally a cumbersome solution.

In this case I think you'd be best served with either writing out the methods, after perhaps restructuring the classes somewhat. So that you have all of your logic written out explicitly, instead of being some sort of meta-language inside PHP itself.
Either that, or using a factory pattern to generate the objects. Which has the required methods explicitly stated, and doing the operations with these objects in the controller instead (of on the container).

When it comes to the second part, I don't quite understand where you get the `$ctn` object from, or the relation of the `SchemaModule` in it. But, calling other instances from within methods is nothing unusual in OOP, at least not as long as those instances and dependencies are clearly marked.
Most of the time these dependencies are (and should) be provided to the constructor, and then saved in the class itself. Meaning that the controller needs to know the dependencies of the classes, and provide them upon object generation. This again ties into the comment I made above, about spelling your logic out clearly in the code and avoiding the whole "meta God object" situation.

At first glance it might seem that the factory pattern is more of the same of this fuzzy logic pattern, since it too generates objects dynamically depending upon some input. The big difference here is that the objects it creates are all based upon classes which share an interface, so that you know they are compatible and mutually-interchangable.
This is what I think you're missing in your code, by and large.

Comment: Thank you ChristianF. I think I got something cannot yet explain. The one that I realize, I was trying to get "meta God object" without knowledge and didn't know that I should avoid.

Comment: @user3477339: You're welcome, and I'm glad I could help. Thanks for upvoting and accepting the answer. :)
I also recommend www.phptherightway.com for further reading, as it'll give you lots of really good information on how to use PHP the best way possible.